# How to know if a result is expected or not?

Tags: regression

I have two students whose exam results are 50, 60, 45, 55. In the next exam, student A got 70, student B got 50. Imagine I have thousands of students like this. Based on the previous exam results, student B is expected to get that 50. However, student A is not expected to get 70. How can I use statistics to determine this kind of difference? Can I use statistical significance or p-value... etc?

Comment: If you believe a student's ability on the 5th exam is represented by the same normal dist'n as on the 1st four exams, then a 95% prediction interval for the score on the 5th exam would be $\bar X \pm t^*\sqrt{1 + S^2/4},$ where $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are computed from the first four exams and $t^*$ cuts 2.5% from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with df=3. For your exmp, that gives $(41.7,63.3).$ So in that case, you'd be surprised to see a 70 on the 5th. Of course, there always lurks the possibility (however slight) that the student finally got serious about studying for the 5th exam.